# java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.laptopsdb.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist (July 2022)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

*Yes I have already tried some old guides, I described it below.*

I created new project for Room Database in Kotlin Android. I followed the official google documentation for it.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

If I follow as per documentation I get error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.laptopsdb.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

I also tried changing room-runtime to room-ktx but the error is same. Moreover, I tried adding id 'kotlin-kapt' and changing annotationProcessor to kapt but that give me following error, errors actually, bunch of them, while auto opening UserDao.java file

https://github.com/subjectOneThree/StackOverFLowShares/blob/main/Screenshot_20220715_215040.png

My code is almost stock according to documentation, however you can checkout if I made any stupid mistake

**build.gradle (app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    //id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.laptopsdb"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    //implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    //kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

**User.kt**

```
@Entity (tableName = "laptops")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)
```

**UserDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM laptops")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    suspend fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
            "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(user: User)
}
```

**AppDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "laptops"
        ).build()

        val userDao = db.userDao()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            userDao.insertAll(User(2,"Hello","World"))

            val users: List<User> = userDao.getAll()
            Log.d("Room Activity", users.toString())
        }


    }
}
```

Some of the older project, and a project from my friend have exactly the same code (as far as I have looked into it) and they are working fine. But now when I am trying to create new project it is giving me error. I have tried building several projects before posting here.

Comment: You should implement room database as a _singleton_. Don't instantiate it inside the activity.  I highly suggest you complete the [android room codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0)  to learn the the proper implementation of android room database

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I will surely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (comment) doing this:

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "laptops"
        ).build()
```

in the onCreate of mainActivity is a very bad way of creating a database instance, unless you want multiple database instances in one app!

2. solution:

try changing your build.gradle to this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.laptopsdb"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

EDIT:
After creating a project with the same code you have I noticed some rather strange bugs:

1. in your User.kt file you declared the table name of that entity to "laptops", but in your UserDao you still refered to a table named user, which does not exist (???), that's why room had some troubles with your dao
2. You declare your uid as Primary Key, which SHOULD NEVER be a duplicate, every single one of the keys should differ, yet in your main activity you use "userDao.insertAll(User(2,"Hello","World"))", which will result in a crash on second run, just remove that line
3. using "GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)" to run a coroutine isn't really encouraged, GlobalScope is even marked in the android studio as a delicate API and using it without proper knowledge first may result in strange bugs or even memory leaks, just use a viewModel to handle all of the work
4. As I also stated before,

```
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "laptops"
        ).build()
```

do not use that to create database instance

5. update your build.gradle to:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.laptopsdb"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // you may add the variable, just keep the version correct
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0-alpha02"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02"

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

and the dao to:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM laptops")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    suspend fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
            "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(user: User)
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the respond. However, for point 1. I get the idea, but as a newbie I followed the android documentation. If there are issues then why Google put it in the official documentation on the first place. Why I'm getting bugs when I literally tried copy pasting the exact code? Thanks again.

Comment: firstly: did it work or not?
secondly: google cannot update all of their decumentation after every minor changes (unfortunately)

Comment: Hello JustSightseeing, i tried option 2 but it returned the same errors as it does with id 'kotlin-kapt' . You can check my gradle file on the following link   https://github.com/subjectOneThree/StackOverFLowShares/blob/main/build.gradle  **errors on this file** https://github.com/subjectOneThree/StackOverFLowShares/blob/main/Screenshot_20220715_215040.png

Comment: No worries, I think I figured it out, I will update my answer now

Comment: thank you so much. can't believe it was syntax error after all. It worked now. Point 1 and 2 were my stupid mistakes and these two were primarily the reason i guess. As of 3 and 4, I haven't touched them yet because singleton and coroutines are still new topics for me. That said, I will obviously look into them now. Thank You, I will mark it as solution.

Comment: No worries, just don't give up, android sometimes isn't the easiest to understand but after you do, it feels very good :D